# unsuccessful call of rstan

Tags: r, rstan

all.

I try to call `rstan` by `library(rstan)` However, I got the message below.
I was wondering how I can successfully call `rstan`.
It seems that I succeeded to install it.

```
Loading required package: StanHeaders
Loading required package: ggplot2
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rstan’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rstan', details:
  call: get_rng(0)
  error: function 'Rcpp_precious_remove' not provided by package 'Rcpp'
In addition: Warning messages:
1: package ‘rstan’ was built under R version 4.1.2 
2: package ‘StanHeaders’ was built under R version 4.1.2 
3: package ‘ggplot2’ was built under R version 4.1.2
```

Thank you,

Comment: You need to update your version of Rcpp. Try `install.packages('Rcpp')`

Comment: I tried and still see the message below.
rstan (Version 2.21.2, GitRev: 2e1f913d3ca3)
For execution on a local, multicore CPU with excess RAM we recommend calling
options(mc.cores = parallel::detectCores()).
To avoid recompilation of unchanged Stan programs, we recommend calling
rstan_options(auto_write = TRUE)
Do not specify '-march=native' in 'LOCAL_CPPFLAGS' or a Makevars file
Warning messages:
1: package ‘rstan’ was built under R version 4.1.2 
2: package ‘StanHeaders’ was built under R version 4.1.2 
3: package ‘ggplot2’ was built under R version 4.1.2

Comment: That looks fine. That's not an error.